# asterisk getoption with concatenated prompts

Tags: java, concatenation, asterisk, agi

The question speaks for itself. I would like to run the getoption method of the fastagi.AgiChannel, but with concatenated prompts, like you would do Background(press-1&or&press-2) in the dialplan directly.
I tried all variations and searched everywhere on the net but couldn't find.
I'm programming in java using eclipse.
Below the code.

```
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiChannel;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiException;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiRequest;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.BaseAgiScript;

public class HelloAgiScript extends BaseAgiScript{

    @Override
    public void service(AgiRequest arg0, AgiChannel arg1) throws AgiException {
        int choice;
        // Answer the channel
        answer();
        //say hello
        streamFile("silence/1");
        streamFile("welcome");
        //Ask for an input and give feedback
        choice=getOption("press-1","1,2"); //Here is where I would like to prompt press-1 or press-2
        sayDigits(String.valueOf(choice-48));
        streamFile("silence/1");
        //and hangup
        hangup();   
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. As arehops suggested, you can't use getOption with multiple files.
I was not able to replicate his proposal, but found this implementation that works, using the exec and AgiReply:

```
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiChannel;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiException;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiRequest;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.BaseAgiScript;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.reply.AgiReply;

public class HelloAgiScript extends BaseAgiScript {

    @Override
    public void service(AgiRequest arg0, AgiChannel arg1) throws AgiException {
        String choice;
        // Answer the channel
        answer();
        //say hello
        streamFile("silence/1");
        streamFile("welcome");
        //Ask for an input and give feedback
        System.out.println("test");
        exec("Background","press-1&or&press-2&silence/3"); //Executes Background application
        AgiReply agiReply = getLastReply(); //Get the reply in the form of an AgiReply object
        choice=agiReply.getResult(); //Extract the actual reply
        choice=Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(choice)); // convert from ascii to actual digit
        System.out.println("choice: "+choice);
        streamFile("silence/1");
        sayDigits(choice);
        streamFile("silence/1");
        //and hangup
        hangup();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use getOption with multiple files.

But you can get rid of that strange java firmware and use asterisk AGI.

```
ExecCommand("Read(result,press-1&or&press-2,1,,3)");
choice=getVariable("result");
```

For more info see

http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/apidocs/index.html

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Read

Comment: Thanks.I was not able to implement it as is. But knowing that it was not possible with getOption pushed me to look for other solutions, and I came back with the one I posted.